# Add price if length is greater then 2 using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){
    if (jQuery('li.gfield').hasClass('trustee')) {
        var trustee = (jQuery('.trustee').length > 2); 
    }
    total += trusteeadd ; 
    return total;
});
```

I am tring to add price in total if class length is greater then 2 i have used the above function but it only works for length = 3 not for 4 or 5 and so on please help how this can be done

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to determine the amount of classes a certain element has? See `classList`, it'll return an array of which you can check `.length` of.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope what you want to do is if more than 2 element have `trustee` class then you want them to add with `trusteeadd`. Try like below.

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){ 
    if (jQuery('li.gfield').hasClass('trustee')) {
        var count = jQuery('.trustee').length;
        var trusteeadd = 1 * 35; 
        // add if length > 2 
        total = (count > 2) ? (total + trusteeadd * (count - 2)) : total; 
    } 
    return total; 
});
```